# Why is the compiler giving me an error on my set_intersection?

Tags: c++, set, set-intersection

I have a class which has two attributes :

```
 set< int > ens1_;
 set< int > ens2_;
```

Now, I have a method which finds the intersection between these two sets. Here is what I wrote in my method:

```
set< int > ens;
set< int >::iterator it;

it = set_intersection(ensEntier1_.begin(), ensEntier1_.end(), ensEntier2_.begin(), ensEntier2_.end(), ens.begin());
return ens;
```

It gives me an error at compile inside the stl_algo.h but I don't know from where to start to correct the error

Thank you for your time

Etienne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 5th argument to the `set_intersection` overload you're calling expects an output iterator; `ens.begin()` does **not** return an output iterator. Try this instead:

```
set<int> ens;
set_intersection(
    ens1_.begin(),
    ens1_.end(),
    ens2_.begin(),
    ens2_.end(),
    inserter(ens, ens.end())
);
return ens;
```

Note: make sure you `#include <iterator>`.

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved my problem ! Thanks to everyone also for your suggestions !

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to use something like an `insert_iterator` for your result.

It's also unclear how the `ensEntier1_` and `ensEntier2_` you're passing to `set_intersection` correspond to `ens1_` and `ens2_`, but for the moment I'll assume they do.

Edit: here's a working example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

int main(){ 

    std::set<int> set1;
    std::set<int> set2;

    set1.insert(1);
    set1.insert(2);
    set1.insert(5);

    set2.insert(2);
    set2.insert(3);
    set2.insert(5);

    std::set<int> result;

    std::set_intersection(set1.begin(), set1.end(), 
                          set2.begin(), set2.end(), 
                          std::inserter(result, result.end()));
    std::copy(result.begin(), result.end(), 
              std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`set_intersection` must write to a sequence container such as `vector`, not an associative container such as `set`, if the container's native iterators are used.

Try this:

```
vector< int > ens( min( ensEntier1_.size(), ensEntier2_.size() );
vector< int >::iterator it;

it = set_intersection(ensEntier1_.begin(), ensEntier1_.end(), ensEntier2_.begin(), ensEntier2_.end(), ens.begin());
ens.erase( it, ens.end() );
return ens;
```

Comment: Why would it need a sequence? It appears to require only an output iterator.

Comment: @Jerry: Right. I'll let you cover the insert_iterator alternative… personally I tend to use `vector` and `sort` for this kind of thing…

Comment: Using vector and sort is fine (in fact, quite possibly superior). You still need to either use a back_inserter, or (as you've done above) allocate enough space for the result ahead of time.